# How to choose prepositions after "cheat"

Tags: prepositions, british-english

Which prepositions do we have to choose after the verb "cheat"?

- cheat in exams
- cheat at exams
- cheat in tests
- cheat at tests
- cheat in cards
- cheat at cards

  Which ones are correct in British English?

Comment: In AmE, we'd use "on" for exams or tests... I think Brits are different... which type of English are you interested in?

Comment: We Brits use "cheat on" to mean being unfaithful to your partner. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cheat-on-sb

Comment: I am interested in British English.

Comment: @JavaL - AmE uses _cheat on_ when talking about infidelity, too; however, you can cheat on a test, or cheat on your wife (though I'd only parse the latter as a phrasal verb).

Answer (score 4):

**British English**

As a vague, general rule, we cheat *at* activities that don't have a distinct beginning and end. So we can:

- cheat at cards
- cheat at football

However, if the activity has a specific beginning and end then we can cheat *in* it:

- cheat in the exam
- cheat in the semi-final

Answer (score 0):

The preposition one uses varies

> Cheat **on** *someone*  *( someone is the person being cheated )*
>   Cheat **with** *someone* *( someone is the accomplice )*
>
> Cheat **on** an exam
>   Cheat **on** a test
>   Cheat **in** an exam *( also acceptable )*
>   Cheat **in** a test
>
> Cheat **at** cards  *( usually used for games )*
>   Cheat **at** checkers
>
> Cheat **in** a race  *( to show when )*
>   Cheat **before** starting
>   Cheat **after** the fact

it just depends on what you want to say.

Comment: Double checking... "on" is acceptable in British English when referring to tests/exams?

Answer (score -2):

> to cheat on somebody

(be unfaithful to)

> to cheat somebody at cards

Comment: What is "sb"? Please use full words.

Comment: @Catija Sb is the abbreviation seen in all good learners dictionaries and efl coursebooks.

Comment: @Catija See second definition [here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/tell)